# Merging columns from two Pandas dataframes and showing the source for each row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two Pandas dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd
a = pd.DataFrame( {'key' : [123, 234, 345, 456] } )
b = pd.DataFrame( {'key' : [     234, 345, 456, 567 ] } )
```

What I'd like to do is merge them into a single dataframe with two columns: one `key`, the union of both; and the other `source`, a list of which of the two original dataframes contained said key.

For the above input, I want this:

```
+---+-----+--------+
|   | key | source |
+---+-----+--------+
| 0 | 123 | [a]    |
| 1 | 234 | [a, b] |
| 2 | 345 | [a, b] |
| 3 | 456 | [a, b] |
| 4 | 567 | [b]    |
+---+-----+--------+
```

I have an implementation which works, but (I imagine) is hideously slow for large tables:

```
union = set( a.key )
union.update( b.key )
union_series = pd.Series( data=sorted(list(union)) )

def append_ifin_src( urow, acc, (name, src) ):
    acc.extend( [name] if len(src[src==urow]) != 0 else [] )
    return acc

source_series = union_series.apply( lambda urow : reduce( lambda acc, tocheck : append_ifin_src(urow, acc, tocheck), [('a', a.key), ('b', b.key)], [] ) )

pd.DataFrame( { 'key' : union_series, 'source' : source_series } )
```

What's a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd  

a = pd.DataFrame( {'key' : [123, 234, 345, 456],
                  'source': ['a','a','a','a'] } )
b = pd.DataFrame( {'key' : [     234, 345, 456, 567 ],
                   'source': ['b','b','b','b']} )

df = a.merge(b, how='outer', on='key').fillna("")
df['source'] = df['source_x'] +df['source_y']
df[['key', 'source']]
```

Adding a column to the original dataframes is another idea...

Answer (score 0):

A "pandy" way to do this would be to first promote the columns to indexes:

```
aa = pd.DataFrame(['a']*len(a), index=a.key, columns=['a'])
bb = pd.Series(['b']*len(b), index=b.key, name='b')
```

and then join them and calculating a new column:

```
aa.join(bb, how='outer')\
  .fillna('')\
  .apply(lambda x: x['a'] + x['b'], axis=1)
```

I would also try a pure python solution if the initial ordering is not important:

```
def source(key):
    if key in sa and key in sb:
        return '[a, b]'
    if key in sa:
        return '[a]'
    if key in sb:
        return '[b]'

sa = set(a.key)
sb = set(b.key)
pd.DataFrame([[key, source(key)] 
              for key in sa.union(sb)], 
              columns=['key', 'source'])     
Out[99]:
key source
0   456 [a, b]
1   234 [a, b]
2   567 [b]
3   345 [a, b]
4   123 [a]
```

In my quick tests the pure python was 6 times faster but you should check with your own data.

Answer (score 0):

If adding a column isn't an option you can use `np.in1d` after the merge.  This gets most of the way there except you have empty strings to remove.

```
df = pd.merge(a, b, how='outer')
df['source'] = zip(np.where(np.in1d(df, a), 'a', ''), 
                   np.where(np.in1d(df, b), 'b', ''))

   key  source
0  123   (a, )
1  234  (a, b)
2  345  (a, b)
3  456  (a, b)
4  567   (, b)
```